# How to compute Push Forward Measures?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, borel-measures, pushforward

Given the measure space $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda|_{[0,1]})$ , I am asked to find the push forward measure $\mu$ of the measurable function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^{3}$.

My question is that how do I explicitly calculate $\mu(A)$ for any Borel set in $[0,1]$?

Now I know that $\mu(A)=\lambda(f^{-1}(A))$ . That is $\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:x^{3}\in A\})$ . Now I don't understand how to compute the right hand side for arbitrary Borel sets $A$. But I do know how to find $\mu(a,b)$ ( or $\mu((a,b])$ ) for any interval $(a,b]$ . That is simply $\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]: a<x^{3}\leq b\}) = \lambda(\{x\in[0,1] : \sqrt[3]{a}<x\leq \sqrt[3]{b}\}) = \lambda\bigg((\sqrt[3]{a},\sqrt[3]{b}]\bigg) = \sqrt[3]{b}-\sqrt[3]{a}$ . I mention this because, I know that the collection $\{(a,b]\subset [0,1]\}$ generates the Borel Sigma Algebra on $[0,1]$ .  So intuitively , I can recover $\mu(A)$ for any Borel set $A$ but how(is it possible?) to calculate explicitly what $\mu(A)$ will be?(If it is possible)

Also , I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090318/equality-of-push-forward-measure-and-borel-measure) post and it seems that the issue is related to that of a pdf of a random variable . So if we write it as $\displaystyle\mu(A)=\int_{A\cap[0,1]}\dfrac{1}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}}d\lambda$ then we seem to be able to compute it. But it is still not explicitly possible to calculate this integral over all Borel sets $A$ right? .

So what is the correct description?

I also read about the [Caratheodory's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem#Introductory_statement) which also allows me to extend $\mu$ from the subsets of the form $(a,b]$ to any Borel set but it still does not give an explicit description.

Edit: I am sorry if I could not explain myself properly. What I am trying to ask is: Is there a complete description of $\mu(A)$ in terms of $\lambda|_[0,1](A)$? . So if you were asked to "find the push forward measure" then what answer and in what form  would you give or would consider a "valid" one?

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense: we can't indeed compute many simple integrals exactly, or give a exact decimal representation of an irrational number. In mathematics many things are not computable, at most you can get an aaproximation. In first place many Borel sets doesn't have a constructive definition!

Comment: @Masacroso I am sorry if I could not explain myself properly. What I am trying to ask is: Is there a complete description of $\mu(A)$ in terms of $\lambda|_[0,1](A)$? . So if you were asked to "find the push forward measure" then what answer and in what form  would you give?

Comment: Concerning its description there is nothing more to gain then providing CDF or PDF.

Comment: You’re really just asking how to describe a Borel measure. A Borel measure can be written as the sum of an absolutely continuous measure and a singular one. In any nice example, the singular one is a sum of delta measures. Find the two terms.

Comment: @Deane So if I give the description of the pdf or if I say that since this countable additive measure on the algebra of all finite union of disjoint intervals of the form $(a,b]$ , then by Caratheodory Extension theorem it extends to a unique measure on the Borel sigma algebra , then would you consider it a proper  and sufficiently complete description of the push forward $\mu$?

Comment: If there is no singular part, then the answer should be of the form $h(x)\,dx$.

Comment: You mean $\int h(x)\,dx$ right? Where h is the pdf. Here there cannot be a singular part as it has a pdf and so it is absolutely continuous with the Lebesgue Measure. @Deane

Comment: Yes, that’s right.